# Non-Noetherian rings satisfying $\dim R[T]=\dim R+1$

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

What are some examples of non-noetherian rings $R$ for which $\dim R[T]=\dim R+1$ holds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if $\dim R=n$ we have $n+1\le\dim R[T]\le2n+1$. For $n=0$ this gives $\dim R[T]=\dim R+1$. Now choose your favorite ring of dimension zero which is not noetherian.

Comment: If you choose $R$ a countable direct product of (copies of) $\mathbb F_2$, then notice that $R$ *is* coherent.

Comment: where can I find a proof of the first inequality? Thank you!

Comment: @vevvostar This is Theorem 38 in Kaplansky, *Commutative Rings*.